# How to resolve a "telegram.error.BadRequest: Wrong type of the web page content" error from using Telegram API?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, pythonanywhere

I have written a script to program a Telegram bot to return weather forecast info to the user based on the their choice. There are 3 options: (1) 2 hours forecast; (2) 24 hours forecast; and (3) 4 days forecast. The script resides on pythonanywhere server.

The script will call the weather forecast website's API for the info.

The info is then consolidated into a pandas dataframe before it is saved as a png file.

The purpose is to get the Telegram bot to send the png file back to the user using `update.message.reply_photo(response)`. `response` is a HTTPS link that opens up to an image that's saved on pythonanywhere server.

After running my script, I was met with the `telegram.error.BadRequest: Wrong type of the web page content` error. I was confused about this as the Telegram API documentation states that URL is accepted as an argument.

I have included my script and the traceback message below. I have masked out my API token and username on purpose. This is substituted with `<purposely_masked_out>`.

FYI: I have ran the script on my local machine and it worked fine. The difference between the script hosted on pythonanywhere (the one that's giving me the error) vs the one on my local machine is the argument that was passed to `update.message.reply_photo(response)`. The difference is as follows:

*Local Machine: Script saves the png file on my Desktop and response was referring to the png's filename.

Pythonanywhere: Script saves the png file in my pythonanywhere folder and the response was referring to the png's URL. I'm unsure if it's because the file requires logging into pythonanywhere to access it.*

Please help.

**My script: **

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
from typing import Final
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, ContextTypes
import df2img

BOT_TOKEN: Final = <purposely_masked_out>
BOT_USERNAME: Final = <purposely_masked_out>

async def start_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await update.message.reply_text('Hi! You can check the SG weather by typing \'2 hours\', \'24 hours\' or \'4 days\'')

def handle_response(text: str) -> str:
    # 2 hours weather data extraction
    if '2 hours' in text:
        two_r = requests.get('https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/environment/2-hour-weather-forecast').json()
        two_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['area', 'forecast'])

        for i in range(len(two_r['items'][0]['forecasts'])):
            two_df.loc[i] = [(two_r['items'][0]['forecasts'][i]['area']),
                             (two_r['items'][0]['forecasts'][i]['forecast'])]

        fig = df2img.plot_dataframe(two_df)
        df2img.save_dataframe(fig=fig, filename='SG 2 hour weather.png')
        return 'https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/<purposely_masked_out>/files/home/<purposely_masked_out>/SG 2 hour weather.png'

    # 24 hours weather data extraction
    elif '24 hours' in text:
        two_four_r = requests.get('https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/environment/24-hour-weather-forecast').json()

        # compiling the forecast data
        forecast = list(two_four_r['items'][0]['periods'][0]['regions'].values())
        temp_list = []

        for i in range(1, 3):
            temp_list.extend(list(two_four_r['items'][0]['periods'][i]['regions'].values()))

        for x in range(len(temp_list)):
            forecast.append(temp_list[x])

        # compiling the region data
        region = list(two_four_r['items'][0]['periods'][0]['regions'].keys()) * 3

        # compiling the period data
        period = ['first 8 hours'] * 5 + ['next 8 hours'] * 5 + ['subsequent 8 hours'] * 5

        # compiling all 3 above together
        d = {}
        d['forecast'] = forecast
        d['region'] = region
        d['period'] = period

        # convert into a dataframe for extraction
        two_four_df = pd.DataFrame(d)
        two_four_df = two_four_df[['period', 'region', 'forecast']]

        fig = df2img.plot_dataframe(two_four_df)
        df2img.save_dataframe(fig=fig, filename='SG 24 hour weather.png')
        return 'https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/<purposely_masked_out>/files/home/<purposely_masked_out>/SG 24 hour weather.png'

    # 4 days weather data extraction
    elif '4 days' in text:
        four_day_r = requests.get('https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/environment/4-day-weather-forecast').json()
        four_day_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['forecast'])

        for i in range(4):
            four_day_df.loc[i] = [four_day_r['items'][0]['forecasts'][i]['forecast']]

        fig = df2img.plot_dataframe(four_day_df)
        df2img.save_dataframe(fig=fig, filename='SG 4 days weather.png')
        return 'https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/<purposely_masked_out>/files/home/<purposely_masked_out>/SG 4 day weather.png'

    else:
        return 'I don\'t understand. Please select between \'2 hours\', \'24 hours\' or \'4 days\' and type them properly without spacing'

async def handle_message(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    text: str = update.message.text
    response = handle_response(text)

    await update.message.reply_photo(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Starting bot...')
    app = Application.builder().token(BOT_TOKEN).build()

    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start_command))
    app.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, handle_message))

    print('Polling...')
    app.run_polling(poll_interval=3)
```

**Traceback Message:**

```
No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/<purposely_masked_out>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/ext/_application.py", line 1184, in process_update
    await coroutine
  File "/home/<purposely_masked_out>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/ext/_basehandler.py", line 141, in handle_update
    return await self.callback(update, context)
  File "/home/<purposely_masked_out>/sg-weather-telegram-bot.py", line 89, in handle_message
    await update.message.reply_photo(response)
  File "/home/<purposely_masked_out>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/_message.py", line 1391, in reply_photo
    return await self.get_bot().send_photo(
  File "/home/<purposely_masked_out>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/ext/_extbot.py", line 2655, in send_photo
    return await super().send_photo(
  File "/home/<purposely_masked_out>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/_bot.py", line 394, in decorator
    result = await func(self, *args, **kwargs)  # skipcq: PYL-E1102
  File "/home/<purposely_masked_out>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/_bot.py", line 1055, in send_photo
    return await self._send_message(
  File "/home/<purposely_masked_out>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/ext/_extbot.py", line 517, in _send_message
    result = await super()._send_message(
  File "/home/<purposely_masked_out>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/_bot.py", line 572, in _send_message
    result = await self._post(
  File "/home/<purposely_masked_out>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/_bot.py", line 482, in _post
    return await self._do_post(
  File "/home/<purposely_masked_out>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/ext/_extbot.py", line 335, in _do_post
    return await super()._do_post(
  File "/home/<purposely_masked_out>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/_bot.py", line 510, in _do_post
    return await request.post(
  File "/home/<purposely_masked_out>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/request/_baserequest.py", line 168, in post
    result = await self._request_wrapper(
  File "/home/<purposely_masked_out>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/request/_baserequest.py", line 325, in _request_wrapper
    raise BadRequest(message)
telegram.error.BadRequest: Wrong type of the web page content
```

Comment: In my experience, TG is sometimes a bit pickly when it comes to accepting URLs for sending pictures. Please double check that the URLs can be openend as expected, that they just display the picture (no "immediate download", no additional GUI) and maybe also check if the correct mime type can be inferred from the URL

Answer (score 0):

> I'm unsure if it's because the file requires logging into
> pythonanywhere to access it

Exactly -- on PythonAnywhere urls like `https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/username/files/...` are accessible only to the logged user `username` via browser.  If you want to share your files programmatically, you need to serve them accordingly.